# Calling web project function from console project in same solution causing issue C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, console

I am facing an issue when trying to call a function present in my web application from Console application.

My solution has two projects 
My solution
  - Web Project
  - Console Project

Code of my Console Application that calls web project function

```
namespace testConsoleApp
{
    class mainClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");

            try
            {
                outlookRoomBooking objOutlook = new outlookRoomBooking();
                objOutlook.updateStatus();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("cron completed.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Code of my Web Porject that i am using

```
namespace LVIS.includes
{
    public class outlookRoomBooking
    {

        private string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"].ToString();
        private string passowrd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["passowrd"].ToString();

        //Some more codes here //
    }
}
```

When I run my console application, I get error "object reference not set to an instance of an object" when control enters the class in my web application i.e first line
private string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"].ToString();

I have added link reference of web.config of web project in my console project.

it seems class is not able to access ConfigurationManager.AppSettings when called from console application. class works fine when called from the same web project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run my console application, I get error "object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object" when control enters the class in my
>   web application i.e first line private string user =
>   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"].ToString();

Probably because the `<appSettings>` present in the whole Web app aren't present in the `app.config` of your console app.

Application settings are loaded from the application configuration file (i.e. `web.config` or `app.config`) present in the base directory of the application. In your case, the base application directory of a console app is the location of the *executable*.

***TL;DR version***: Copy and paste application settings from the `web.config` to your console app's `app.config`.

Comment: Thanks @Matias, It worked this way, but I had used "Add link" in my console application for web.config present in my web project to avoid maintaining .config file at two places but that did not work.

Comment: @Chandikumar I see, well, I'm glad you solved the issue ;)